# The resource from “http://localhost:3000/script.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to transfer all the JavaScript to a separate js file and then adding that js file to the html like the usual practice. But console shows the following error -

```
The resource from “http://localhost:3000/public/main.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

I have build a socket.io basic chat application in Nodejs and express which works on the http server.

```js
const { Socket } = require("dgram");

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);


app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  //res.setHeader('content-type','application/javascript')
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
}); 

var user = "";

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on('userName', (person) => {
      user = person;
      console.log(person + " connected");
  });
  
  socket.on('chat message', (data) => {
    //console.log('message: ' + msg);
    io.emit('chat message',{user: data.sending_user,message: data.message});
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
     console.log(user+" disconnected");
  });
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("listening on *:3000");
});
```

the client side html code -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Chat</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="/main.js" ></script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding-bottom: 3rem;
            font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        #form {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            padding: 0.25rem;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            display: flex;
            height: 3rem;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        }

        #input {
            border: none;
            padding: 0 1rem;
            flex-grow: 1;
            border-radius: 2rem;
            margin: 0.25rem;
        }

        #input:focus {
            outline: none;
        }

        #form>button {
            background: #333;
            border: none;
            padding: 0 1rem;
            margin: 0.25rem;
            border-radius: 3px;
            outline: none;
            color: #fff;
        }

        #messages {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #messages>li {
            
        }
        #messages .userName {
            font-size: 0.7em;
            padding-top: -0.5em;
            color:darkslateblue;
        }

        
    </style>

    
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="form" action="">
        <input id="input" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    
    
</body>

</html>
```

the main.js javascript for the html file-

```js
var user;

var socket = io();

function myFunction() {
  var person = prompt("Please enter your name:");
  user = person;
  console.log(person + " from html");
  socket.emit("userName", person);
}

var form = document.getElementById("form");
var input = document.getElementById("input");

form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (input.value) {
    socket.emit("chat message", { sending_user: user, message: input.value });
    input.value = "";
  }
});
socket.on("chat message", function (data) {
  var item = document.createElement("li");
  var name = document.createElement("li");
  name.setAttribute("class", "userName");
  name.textContent = data.user;
  item.textContent = data.message;
  messages.appendChild(name);
  messages.appendChild(item);

  window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
});

module.exports = 'main.js';
```

I am guessing there is some problem with serving the js file through the server, Does the content-type have to be specified somewhere explicitly? I haven't found any extra steps in the other code i found on a similar github project.

Answer (score 0):

I read a lot of similar question's answers and their different solutions. Finally I figured out what the real issue was- **incorrect pathing**, the files weren't served and hence a 404 resulted in the above error somehow.

By statically serving all the style and script files and setting the path relative to that location would solve the error

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

[image]

The script tag in the html file-

```html
<script type="application/javascript" src="main.js" ></script>
```